# PHP калькулятор

Tags: winapi, gui, php

Существует "задание"

1. Есть два инпута(места куда вводить значения)
2. Вводить можно туда в разных системах счисления
3. Мы должны определить системы счилсения
4. Перекодировать введнные данные в десятичную систему
5. Сложить их

Это задание надо оформить на php. (это всё делается в программе PHP Devel Studio 2.0)

Так же есть алгоритм "почти готового калькулятора", но в нем имеется ошибка.
алгоритм хорошо считает, но когда появляются больше 2-ух знаков начинает теряться T_T

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
$a = c("perA")->text;
if (!preg_match("/^[A-F0-9]+$/",$a)){
        if (!preg_match("/^[A-B0-9]+$/",$a)){
                if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$a)){
                        if (!preg_match("/^[0-7]+$/",$a)){
                                if (!preg_match("/^[0-2]+$/",$a)){
                                        if (!preg_match("/^[0-1]+$/",$a)){
                                        }
                                                else {
                                                        $a = base_convert($a,2,10);
                                                }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                                $a = base_convert($a,3,10);
                                        }
                                }
                                else {
                                        $a = base_convert($a,8,10);
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                                $a = $a;
                        }
                }
                else {
                        $a = base_convert($a,12,10);
                }
        }
        else {
                $a = base_convert($a,16,10);
        }

$b = c("perB")->text;
if (!preg_match("/^[A-F0-9]+$/",$b)){
        if (!preg_match("/^[A-B0-9]+$/",$b)){
                if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$b)){
                        if (!preg_match("/^[0-7]+$/",$b)){
                                if (!preg_match("/^[0-2]+$/",$b)){
                                        if (!preg_match("/^[0-1]+$/",$b)){
                                        }
                                                else {
                                                        $b = base_convert($b,2,10);
                                                }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                                $b = base_convert($b,3,10);
                                        }
                                }
                                else {
                                        $b = base_convert($b,8,10);
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                                $b = base_convert($b,10,10);
                        }
                }
                else {
                        $b = base_convert($b,12,10);
                }
        }
        else {
                $b = base_convert($b,16,10);
        }

        $convert = ( $a + $b);
    c("ec1")->caption = base_convert($convert,10,2);
    c("ec2")->caption = base_convert($convert,10,3);
    c("ec3")->caption = base_convert($convert,10,4);
    c("ec4")->caption = base_convert($convert,10,5);
    c("ec5")->caption = base_convert($convert,10,8);
    c("ec7")->caption = base_convert($convert,10,12);
    c("ec8")->caption = base_convert($convert,10,16);
    c("ec6")->caption = $convert;
```

Comment: толи я в php мало видел, толи я такого просто не видел...

Comment: что значит "определить системы счисления" (101 - это какая?)

И как вы с гуем из php работаете?

Почему бы, в конце концов, раз уж вы так не любите циклы, не сделать вложенность в 15 пунктов(16->2)?)

Comment: даже за немаленькие деньги разбираться в этом желания нет никакого.

@Palmervan - я тоже думал что много видел :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а вы присмотритесь, там всего-то двойной развернутый цикл) Мне больше интересно, с чего автор вопроса взял, что число 1100 - двоичное, а не семнадцатеричное, например))

Comment: Дык я не о "сложности", а о вложености, правда - какая задача такой и код :)

Вообще заданая ТСом задача - не имеет решения по определению, собственно это и есть **ответ**.

Comment: Да, вы к сожалению правы. Я понял НЕВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ реализации данного алгоритма.Ведь 1101 Может быть и в 16-ричной системе отсчета.
выявить это алгоритмически, невозможно, слишком много факторов вероятности.

Comment: Sh4dow, для php есть гуи. Ведь это PHP Devel Studio 2.0

Comment: @Никита Аристархов я делал гуй для php до того, как это стало модно))) На бамбаламе и винбиндере, просто интересно было, не думал, что что-то новое появилось.

Comment: Ну и раз все все поняли, как бы намекну, что правильнее было бы присвоить оба значения, а потом

    foreach ($vals as &$val) // array($a, $b)
      foreach ($regulars as $num => $reg) { // array(16 => '"/^[A-F0-9]+$/"')
        if (preg_match($reg, $val)) {
          $val = base_convert($val,$num,10);
          break;
          }
        }

Это 80% вашего кода ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, есть для php GUI, программа называется PHP Devel Studio 2.0. Я, когда писал код ,думал, что работая на исключениях, т.е. исключая все возможные варианты ввода, т.е. 1101, всего скорей 2-ичная система счисления, но слишком много факторов, которые влияют на определение системы счисления. Но и собственно задача из род, "а возможно ли...". Но, как говорится: "Я попробовал" (с)

Comment: В следующий раз, надеюсь, будете думать перед тем как пробовать :)